# Why is uploading a file to s3 via the C# AWS SDK giving a permission denied error?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to enable our application to upload files to a specific S3 bucket.  The idea is to lock it down so if that application's access and secret keys get compromised malicious users can't do anything except upload new files.

In order to do this I created a new IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::app-dev-raw-uploads"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Next I saved the policy and went into the policy simulator and tested the S3 `PutObject` action against the `arn:aws:s3:::app-dev-raw-uploads` s3 bucket, and the simulator gave me an allowed/success result.

I then created a new IAM user and attached that policy to the user and saved.  I then generated an access key and secret key for that user and plugged it into my application.  My application then attempted an upload with the following code:

```
    private static async Task PerformUpload(IIngestControllerSettings settings, string destinationPath, string sourcePath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(settings.AwsAccessKey, settings.AwsSecretKey);
        var region = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(settings.AwsRegionName);
        var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, region);
        var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);

        await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(sourcePath, settings.ArchivalStorageServiceContainerName, destinationPath, cancellationToken);
    }
```

This code works perfectly when I use my (temporary) personal AWS keys, but under this user's access/secret key I get:

> Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

*Edit:* Since I am able to upload files with the AWS CLI using these key credentials it seems like the AWS SDK `TransferUtility` class is requiring more permissions than just `PutObject` in order to upload files, but I can't find any reference as to what those would be.

Comment: Did you try using the new user credentials and perform put object to s3 bucket from AWS CLI instead of the SDK and check if the user is able to add new object to s3 bucket?

Comment: With the AWS CLI tool I am able to successfully upload files with this key via `aws cp c:\temp\test.ts s3://app-dev-raw-uploads/`

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the AWS SDK's `TransferUtility` also requires `GetObject` permissions in order to successfully upload files.  The working policy seems to be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::app-dev-raw-uploads",
                "arn:aws:s3:::app-dev-raw-uploads/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```